# Does Black Scholes exhibit the volatility smile?

Tags: implied-volatility, black-scholes

You often hear about the volatility smile. Is that something that occurs within a standard Black Scholes model, with the usual formula for the price of a call?

If we were to observe some call price (e.g., 15), and then derived implied volatilities from the BS formula depending on different strike prices but fixed maturity (i.e, maturity = 1 and strike goes from 80 to 140?), would we then see a smile?

Comment: For reference: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/volatilitysmile.asp

Answer (score 2):

> If we were to observe some call price (e.g., 15), and then derived implied volatilities from the BS formula depending on different strike prices but fixed maturity (i.e, maturity = 1, and strike goes from 80 to 140??), would we then see a smile?

Yes. Market prices for various strikes and a given maturity often have higher implied volatilities from the Black-Scholes model away from at-the-money.

It is not accounted for in the Black-Scholes model in the fact that volatility is not a function of strike, so volatility is assumed to be constant across strikes, but the market does not price options that way.

I don't know that a quantitative theory has ever been proven; I've always just assumed that people are willing to pay slightly more for options deep in or out of the money based on their strategy, but I have no evidence to base that theory on.

Answer (score 2):

The Black-Scholes model was based on assuming lognormal stock price fluctuations with a *constant* volatility. However, the modern practice is to use the Black-Scholes formula not as a *prediction* but merely as a *parametrization* of option prices, where the observed price of a given option at a given time translates to a "local" implied volatility (IV). Thus, when the resulting IV *varies* over strikes and over time, it is parametrizing a *breakdown of the original Black-Scholes assumptions*. Predicting an option price is tautologically reframed as predicting the corresponding IV. At most we can say that if the original Black-Scholes assumptions are *roughly* right, the IV is *roughly* constant.

The volatility smile is an expected result of stock price fluctuations with *heavier tails* than lognormal. That is, sudden very large moves up or down due to news or sentiment shifts, though rare, are *less rare* than the lognormal distribution indicates. (See the work of Nassim Taleb.) In the absence of a replacement for Black-Scholes that *actually* models the more accurate distribution, we patch it up by noting that the further out-of-the-money options are priced *as if* the underlying *lognormal* volatility were higher (a proxy for the heavier tails).